# How to limit the length of text for labels?

Tags: cocoa

This could be really easy but I it's not obvious when I google it.

I have few NSMenuItem items that get populated at runtime and the label can be very long.How do set a limit for the title with the "..." in the middle of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own method to preprocess the text before it is set to the label, and adds in `...` on your own terms.

Comment: Better yet, use the … character, not the ... string.

Comment: that's exactly what I did. I created a NSString category and have a function that takes in a int param that will limit the text length and add in the "..." char at the end of the string. This sure beats having to use NSTextView.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: grab the NSMenuItemCell from the menu item and set its line break mode to NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle